# How the time complexity of this code is coming O(logn)?

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

```
int a = 0, i = N;
while (i > 0) 
{
a += i;
i /= 2;
}
```

How will I calculate the time complexity of the code? Can anyone Explain?

Comment: `log n` typically means: the bigger your input, the complexity will not grow in a linear way anymore. If you start at 2, it will run twice, if you start at 16, it will only be 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is basically the number of times a loop will run. Big O is the worst case complexity that a particular loop can have. For example, if linear search were being used to find K, which is, say the (n-1)th element of an array(0 indexed, starts with 0), the program would have to loop through the entire array to find the element. This would mean that the loop has to run n times in the worst case, giving linear search a time complexity of O(n).

In the case of your problem, i is initally equal to N and decrements by half per iteration. This would mean that when (N/pow(2, m) > 0 the loop terminates. So the loop runs at most m times which log(n).
log(N) = log(pow(2,m)) ==> log(N) = m